# property FunctionUrlConfig not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I tried to build a sam template for the aws lambda url function and got this error while following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-tutorial.html).

I build just fine without it. Is the documentation outdated?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the sam cli version.

Mine was `SAM CLI, version 1.37.0`, upgrade it to `SAM CLI, version 1.89.0` with [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/manage-sam-cli-versions.html#manage-sam-cli-versions-upgrade)